# Output values for my Training Algorithm are going the wrong direction

Tags: javascript, html, neural-network

When I click the train button on my website the output node values travel the same direction and go the wrong direction sometimes.

[image: The training values when I click train]

I tried to solve it by debugging and looking at the weight and node values. But I can't pinpoint the issue.

I put my train function below. I am a new programmer so I was wondering if I could also get some advice on how to clean the code.

```
function train() {
  //Define variables
  var deltaError = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var errorSum = 0;
  var valueCounter = 0;
  var valueCounter2 = 0;
  var numHiddenLayers = hiddenLayers.length;
  var hiddenLayerIndex = 1;
  var deltaWeights_ho = [];
  var error_k = [];
  var deltaWeights_ih = [];
  var error_j = [];
  //Clean inputs and normalize
  inputFeildsInputNode.forEach((inputFeild, index) => {
    cleanedInputs.push((inputFeild.value - min) / (max - min));
    inputNodes[index].value = cleanedInputs[index];
  });
  //Loop through first hidden layer and calculate values for each node of first hidden layer
  hiddenLayers[0].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
    inputNodes.forEach((inputNode, inputIndex) => {
      sum += inputNode.value * inputHiddenWeights[valueCounter].value;
      valueCounter++;
    });
    node.value = sigmoid(sum);
    sum = 0;
  });
  valueCounter = 0;
  sum = 0;
  //Loop through all hidden layers and calculate values for each node of each hidden layer
  while (hiddenLayerIndex < numHiddenLayers) {
    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
      hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
        sum += hiddenNode.value * hiddenHiddenWeights[valueCounter].value;
        valueCounter++;
      });
      node.value = sigmoid(sum);
      sum = 0;


      sum = 0;
    });
    valueCounter = 0;
    sum = 0;
    hiddenLayerIndex++;
    valueCounter2 = 0;

  }
  //Loop through output nodes and calculate values for each output node
  outputNodes.forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
      sum += hiddenNode.value * hiddenOutputWeights[valueCounter].value;
      valueCounter++;
    });
    node.value = sigmoid(sum);
    console.log(node.value);
    valueCounter = 0;
    //Loop through all output nodes and calculate error for each output node
    error_k[nodeIndex] = (inputFeildsOutputNode[nodeIndex].value - node.value);
    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
      deltaWeights_ho[valueCounter2] = -2 * error_k[nodeIndex] * hiddenNode.value * node.value * (1 - node.value);
      hiddenOutputWeights[valueCounter2].value -= deltaWeights_ho[valueCounter2] * learningRate;
      valueCounter2++;

    });

  });
  valueCounter2 = 0;
  valueCounter = 0;
  //Loop through all hidden layers and calculate error for each node of each hidden layer using the error of the output nodes and calculate delta weights for each connection between hidden and output nodes
  hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
    error_j[nodeIndex] = 0;
    error_k.forEach((error, index) => {
      error_j[nodeIndex] += error * hiddenOutputWeights[valueCounter2].value;
      valueCounter2++;
    });
    //error_j[nodeIndex] = error_j[nodeIndex] * node.value * (1 - node.value);
    valueCounter2 = outputNodes.length * valueCounter;
    deltaError = -2 * error_j[nodeIndex] * node.value * (1 - node.value);
  });
  valueCounter2 = 0;
  valueCounter = 0;
  sum = 0;
  hiddenLayerIndex = 1;
  //Loop through all hidden layers and calculate delta weights for each connection between hidden and hidden nodes
  while (hiddenLayerIndex < numHiddenLayers) {
    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
      hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
        deltaError = -2 * error_j[nodeIndex] * node.value * (1 - node.value) * hiddenNode.value;
        hiddenHiddenWeights[valueCounter2].value -= deltaError * learningRate;
        valueCounter2++;
      });

    });
    hiddenLayerIndex++;
  }

  valueCounter = 0;
  sum = 0;
  outputNodes.forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
    console.log(node.value);
  });
  valueCounter2 = 0;
  valueCounter = 0;
  sum = 0;

  console.log("Training the neural network...");
  // Add your neural network training logic here
}
```

Comment: I posted a more precise version of this question should I delete this question or should I leave them both up?

Comment: So I should delete this one.

Comment: You can delete the irrelevant question. Otherwise one question can be marked as "duplicate", but you can't do that, because of reputation, I believe. You should then at least post a link, so people know which one it is.

Comment: Here is the version of the question with a more in depth explanation and code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75932476/19347667

Comment: I tried the answer on the other question, and it made the training go slower but it did not fix the problem.