# How do I get the output values for my neural network go towards the target values when training?

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I have set up a simple neural network, with what I think is the right backpropagation algorithm. And I made a button that every time a click it, it runs a train function which does the forward and backward propagation. However, when I run my train function by clicking the train button, the neural network output values don't go towards the target values. I haven't done thorough testing, but it appears that the output values decrease or increase at the same time, and sometimes in the right direction, other times in the wrong direction. I believe it depends on what the randomly assigned weights are, and what the input values are.

And just as a note I may be training the neural network wrong. And I could be giving the wrong data instead of the actual algorithm being wrong or my code being wrong.

When I enter train mode in my program it asks for a min and max values for the input data values. These values are not changed until the user refreshes the page and starts over. I have been using 1 for the min and 100 for the max. The neural network I built had 3-5 input nodes and various amounts of hidden nodes and layers, then always had 2 output nodes. I used 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 for the inputs and for the target values I did 1 and 0. My goal was to have an output of 1, 0 when there was an arithmetic pattern and 0, 0 when there was no pattern. I never changed my inputs because I think the network should still go to the desired output even if I use the same inputs. Although I could be wrong.

I was expecting the output values to slowly go towards the target values every time I clicked the train button. But instead, both output values generally would travel the same direction and sometimes not towards the right direction. And when there is a specific number of hidden nodes and layers, I dont know the exact number then the output values are NaN.
[Network and min and max values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MphRl.png)
[Too many hidden nodes and layers gives me NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyUeP.png)
[No NaN values but output values wrong direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7mq2.png)

My code is below and the train function is at the bottom.

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMode();
});

var canvas = document.getElementById("network-display");
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  })
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var inputNodes = [];
var outputNodes = [];
var hiddenLayers = [];
var connections = [];
var inputFeildsInputNode = [];
var inputFeildsOutputNode = [];
var cleanedInputs = [];
var inputHiddenWeights = [];
var hiddenHiddenWeights = [];
var hiddenOutputWeights = [];
var inputHiddenValues = [];
var hiddenHiddenValues = [];
var hiddenOutputValues = [];
var hiddenLayerPosition = 0;
var canAddInputNode = true;
var canAddHiddenNode = false;
var canAddHiddenLayer = false;
var canAddOutputNode = false;
var counter = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var counterIndexInput = 0;
var counterIndexHidden = 0;
var numbersOccured = [];
var buildButtonClicked = false;
var trainButtonClicked = false;
var min = 0;
var max = 0;
var learningRate = 0.1;

function setMode() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var mode = form.mode.value;
    //If mode is build, create buttons to add nodes
    if (mode == "build" && trainButtonClicked == false && buildButtonClicked == false) {
        const instructions = document.getElementById("instructions");
        instructions.innerHTML = "Click on the buttons to add nodes to the network. You can add input nodes, hidden nodes, hidden layers, and output nodes. You can also remove nodes and layers. Once you are done building the network, switch to train mode using the mode selector, then click submit.";
        const inputNodeButton = createButton("Add Input Node", addInputNode);
        const hiddenNodeButton = createButton("Add Hidden Node", addHiddenNode);
        
        const hiddenLayerButton = createButton("Add Hidden Layer", addHiddenLayer);
        const outputNodeButton = createButton("Add Output Node", addOutputNode);
        const removeInputNodeButton = createButton("Remove Input Node", removeInputNode);
        const removeHiddenNodeButton = createButton("Remove Hidden Node", removeHiddenNode);
        const removeHiddenLayerButton = createButton("Remove Hidden Layer", removeHiddenLayer);
        const removeOutputNodeButton = createButton("Remove Output Node", removeOutputNode);

        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.innerHTML = "";
        container.appendChild(inputNodeButton);
        container.appendChild(hiddenNodeButton);
        container.appendChild(hiddenLayerButton);
        container.appendChild(outputNodeButton);
        container.appendChild(removeInputNodeButton);
        container.appendChild(removeHiddenNodeButton);
        container.appendChild(removeHiddenLayerButton);
        container.appendChild(removeOutputNodeButton);
        buildButtonClicked = true;
    }
    //If mode is train, create input feilds for input and output nodes
    if(mode == "train" && inputNodes.length > 0 && outputNodes.length > 0 && hiddenLayers.length > 0 && trainButtonClicked == false && buildButtonClicked == true) {
            hiddenLayers.forEach((layer, layerIndex) => {
                layer.forEach((node, index) => {
                    if(node.hiddenLayer == 0) {
                inputNodes.forEach(inputNode => {
                    var weight = new Weight();
                    weight.XPos1 = hiddenLayers[node.hiddenLayer].xPos;
                        weight.XPos2 = inputNode.xPos;
                        weight.YPos2 = inputNode.yPos;
                    weight.hiddenLayerPosition = hiddenLayerPosition;
                    weight.hiddenNode = node;
                    const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
                    const padding = canvas.height / (hiddenLayers[0].length + 1);
                    var spaceBetweenNodes = (canvasHeight) / (hiddenLayers[0].length + 1);
                    weight.YPos1 = padding + (index) * spaceBetweenNodes;
                    inputHiddenWeights.push(weight);
                });
            } else if (node.hiddenLayer > 0) {
                hiddenLayers[node.hiddenLayer - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, index) => {
                    var weight = new Weight();
                    weight.XPos1 = hiddenLayers[node.hiddenLayer].xPos;
                    weight.XPos2 = hiddenLayers[node.hiddenLayer - 1][index].xPos;
                    weight.YPos2 = hiddenLayers[node.hiddenLayer - 1][index].yPos;
                    weight.hiddenLayerPosition = hiddenLayerPosition;
                    weight.hiddenNode = node;
                    const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
                    const padding = canvas.height / (hiddenLayers[node.hiddenLayer - 1].length + 1);
                    var spaceBetweenNodes = (canvasHeight - 2 * padding) / (hiddenLayers[0].length + 1);
                    //weight.YPos1 = padding + (index) * spaceBetweenNodes;
                    weight.YPos1 = node.yPos;
                    hiddenHiddenWeights.push(weight);
                });
            }
                });
                inputHiddenWeights.forEach((weight, index) => {
                    weight.displayWeight(weight);
                });
                hiddenHiddenWeights.forEach((weight, index) => {
                    weight.displayWeight(weight);
                });
            });
            outputNodes.forEach(outputNode => {
                hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, index) => {
                    var weight = new Weight();
                    weight.XPos1 = outputNode.xPos;
                    weight.XPos2 = hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1][index].xPos;
                    weight.YPos2 = hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1][index].yPos;
                    weight.YPos1 = outputNode.yPos;
                    weight.outputNode = outputNode;
                    hiddenOutputWeights.push(weight);
                });
            });
            hiddenOutputWeights.forEach((weight, index) => {
                weight.displayWeight(weight);
            });

        const instructions = document.getElementById("instructions");
        instructions.innerHTML = "Enter the min and max values for the input nodes. Then click submit. Once the min and max are set you will not be able to input values that are out of the range specified.";
        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.innerHTML = "";

        const minInput = createInputFeild("min", "number", "Min");
        const maxInput = createInputFeild("max", "number", "Max");
        const minMaxSubmit = createInputFeild("minMaxSubmit", "submit", "Submit");
        container.appendChild(minInput);
        container.appendChild(maxInput);
        container.appendChild(minMaxSubmit);
        minMaxSubmit.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            instructions.innerHTML = "Now enter the values for the input nodes. And the desired target values for the outputs. Then click train to train the network. Feel free to do this as many times as needed.";
            min = document.getElementById("min").value;
            max = document.getElementById("max").value;
            minMaxEntered = true;
            container.innerHTML = "";
            //Create input feilds for input nodes
        inputFeildsInputNode.forEach(input => {
            container.appendChild(input);
        });

        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        inputFeildsOutputNode.forEach(input => {
            container.appendChild(input);
        });

        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        //Create train button to initiate training
        const trainButton = createButton("Train", train);
        container.appendChild(trainButton);
        });
        trainButtonClicked = true;
}
}


function createButton(text, onClick) {

    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = text;
    button.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    return button;
}

function createInputFeild(id, type, placeholder) {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = id;
    input.type = type;
    input.placeholder = placeholder;
    return input;
}

class InputNode {
    constructor() {
        this.inputValue = 0;
        this.xPos = 0;
        this.yPos = 0;
        this.nodeType = "input";
    }
    drawInputNode(index, totalNodes) {
        drawNode(50, index, totalNodes, this.nodeType, 0);
    }
}

class HiddenNode {
    constructor(layer) {
        this.removed = false;
        this.hiddenValue = 0;
        this.hiddenLayer = layer;
        this.nodeType = "hidden";
        this.xPos = 0;
        this.yPos = 0;
        this.connectedTo = [];
    }
    drawHiddenNode(index, totalNodes) {
        drawNode(150 + (50 * this.hiddenLayer), index, totalNodes, this.nodeType, this.hiddenLayer);

    }
}

class OutputNode {
    constructor() {
        this.outputValue = 0;
        this.nodeType = "output";
        this.xPos = 0;
        this.yPos = 0;
    }
    drawOutputNode(index, totalNodes) {
        drawNode(500, index, totalNodes, this.nodeType, 0);
    }
}

class Connector {
    constructor() {
        this.xPos = 0;
        this.yPos = 0;
        this.duplicates = 0;
    }
}
class Weight {
    constructor() {
        this.xPos;
        this.yPos;
        this.YPos1;
        this.YPos2;
        this.XPos1;
        this.XPos2;
        this.value = Math.random();
        this.hiddenLayerPosition;
        this.hiddenNode;
        this.outputNode;
    }
    displayWeight(weight) {
/*         const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
        const padding = 30;
        const spaceBetweenNodes = (canvasHeight - 2 * padding) / (hiddenLayers.length + 1);
        console.log(weight.hiddenLayerPosition); */
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        if( weight.hiddenNode != undefined) {
        if(weight.hiddenNode.hiddenLayer == 0) {
        if(weight.YPos2 > weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.hiddenNode.xPos - ((weight.hiddenNode.xPos - weight.XPos2) / 4)), (weight.YPos1 + ((weight.YPos2 - weight.YPos1) / 4)));
        } else if(weight.YPos2 == weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.hiddenNode.xPos - 20), weight.YPos1);
        } else if(weight.YPos2 < weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.hiddenNode.xPos - ((weight.hiddenNode.xPos - weight.XPos2) / 4)), (weight.YPos1 - ((weight.YPos1 - weight.YPos2) / 4)));
        } 
    } else if(weight.hiddenNode.hiddenLayer >= 1) {
        if(weight.YPos2 > weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.hiddenNode.xPos - ((weight.hiddenNode.xPos - weight.XPos2) / 4)), (weight.YPos1 + ((weight.YPos2 - weight.YPos1) / 4)));
        } else if(weight.YPos2 == weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.hiddenNode.xPos - 30), weight.YPos1);
        } else if(weight.YPos2 < weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.hiddenNode.xPos - ((weight.hiddenNode.xPos - weight.XPos2) / 4)), (weight.YPos1 - ((weight.YPos1 - weight.YPos2) / 4)));
        } 
    }
}
    if(weight.outputNode != undefined) {
        if(weight.YPos2 > weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.XPos1 - ((weight.XPos1 - weight.XPos2) / 4)), (weight.YPos1 + ((weight.YPos2 - weight.YPos1) / 4)));
        } else if(weight.YPos2 == weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.XPos1 - 20), weight.YPos1);
        } else if(weight.YPos2 < weight.YPos1) {
            ctx.strokeText(weight.value.toFixed(2), (weight.XPos1 - ((weight.XPos1 - weight.XPos2) / 4)), (weight.YPos1 - ((weight.YPos1 - weight.YPos2) / 4)));
        } 
    }
    }
}
function drawNode(xPos, index, totalNodes, nodeType, layer) {

    const spaceBetweenLayers = 100;
    if(nodeType == "input") {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        xPos = spaceBetweenLayers;
    }
    if(nodeType == "hidden") {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
        xPos = inputNodes[0].xPos + spaceBetweenLayers + (spaceBetweenLayers * layer);
        hiddenLayers[layer].xPos = xPos;
    }
    if(nodeType == "output") {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
        xPos = hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].xPos + spaceBetweenLayers;
    }
    const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    const padding = canvas.height / (totalNodes + 1);
    //const spaceBetweenNodes = (canvasHeight - 2 * padding) / (totalNodes + 1);
    const spaceBetweenNodes = (canvasHeight) / (totalNodes + 1);
    const yPos = padding + index * spaceBetweenNodes;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    
    if(nodeType == "input") {
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.strokeText("I" + index, xPos, yPos);

    } else if(nodeType == "hidden") {
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.strokeText("H" + index, xPos, yPos);
        
    } else if(nodeType == "output") {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.strokeText("O" + index, xPos, yPos);
        
    }
    
    ctx.stroke();

    var counter1 = 0;
    if (nodeType == "hidden" && layer == 0) {
/*             hiddenLayers[0].forEach(node => {
                inputNodes.forEach(inputNode => {
                        inputHiddenWeights.push(new Weight());
                        inputHiddenWeights[counter1].xPos1 = xPos;
                        inputHiddenWeights[counter1].yPos1 = yPos;
                        inputHiddenWeights[counter1].xPos2 = inputNode.xPos;
                        inputHiddenWeights[counter1].yPos2 = inputNode.yPos;
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.stroke();
                        console.log("inputHiddenWeights:" + inputHiddenWeights[counter1].value);
                        if(inputNode.yPos > yPos) {
                            ctx.strokeText(inputHiddenWeights[counter1].value, (xPos - ((xPos - inputNode.xPos) / 4)), (yPos + ((inputNode.yPos - yPos) / 4)));
                        } else if(inputNode.yPos == yPos) {
                            ctx.strokeText(inputHiddenWeights[counter1].value, (xPos - 20), yPos);
                        } else if(inputNode.yPos < yPos) {
                            ctx.strokeText(inputHiddenWeights[counter1].value, (xPos - ((xPos - inputNode.xPos) / 4)), (yPos - ((yPos - inputNode.yPos) / 4)));
                        }
                    counter1++;
                });
            }); */
        hiddenLayers[layer][index].xPos = xPos;
        hiddenLayers[layer][index].yPos = yPos;
        redrawInputHiddenConnections(xPos, yPos, index, counter1, totalNodes);
    } else if (nodeType == "hidden" && layer > 0) {
        hiddenLayers[layer][index].xPos = xPos;
        hiddenLayers[layer][index].yPos = yPos;
        redrawHiddenHiddenConnections(xPos, yPos, hiddenLayers[layer - 1], index);
    }
    if (nodeType == "input") {
        inputNodes[index].xPos = xPos;
        inputNodes[index].yPos = yPos;
    }
    if (nodeType == "output") {
        outputNodes[index].xPos = xPos;
        outputNodes[index].yPos = yPos;
        redrawHiddenOutputConnections(xPos, yPos);
    }

}


function addInputNode() {
    if (canAddInputNode == true) {
        var node = new InputNode();
        inputNodes.push(node);
        redrawAllNodes();
        canAddHiddenNode = true;
        inputFeildsInputNode.push(createInputFeild("input" + inputNodes.length, "number", "Input " + inputNodes.length));
    }

}

function addHiddenNode() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (canAddHiddenNode == true) {
            // Save the context state
        // Save the context state
        // Set the fillStyle
        // Perform your drawing operations
        // Restore the context state
        if (!hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerPosition]) {
            hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerPosition] = [];
        }
        var node = new HiddenNode(hiddenLayerPosition);
        hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerPosition].push(node);
        
        
        redrawAllNodes();
        canAddHiddenLayer = true;
        canAddOutputNode = true;
        counter2++;
    }
    
}

function addHiddenLayer() {

    if(canAddHiddenLayer == true) {
    hiddenLayerPosition++;
    canAddHiddenLayer = false;
    }
}
function addOutputNode() {
    if (canAddOutputNode == true) {
        var node = new OutputNode();
        outputNodes.push(node);
        redrawAllNodes();
        inputFeildsOutputNode.push(createInputFeild("output" + outputNodes.length, "number", "Output " + outputNodes.length));
    }
}

function removeInputNode() {
    inputNodes.pop();
    redrawAllNodes();
}

function removeHiddenNode() {
    if (hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerPosition] && hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerPosition].length > 0) {
        hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerPosition].pop();
    }
    redrawAllNodes();
}

function removeHiddenLayer() {
    if (hiddenLayerPosition > 0) {
        hiddenLayers.pop();
        hiddenLayerPosition--;
    }
    redrawAllNodes();
}
function removeOutputNode() {
    outputNodes.pop();
    redrawAllNodes();
}
function redrawAllCanvas() {
    redrawAllNodes();

}
function redrawInputHiddenConnections(xPos, yPos, index, counter1, totalNodes) {
    
    inputNodes.forEach((inputNode) => {
        hiddenLayers[0][index].connectedTo.push(inputNode);
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        
        ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
        
        ctx.lineTo(inputNode.xPos, inputNode.yPos);
        
        ctx.stroke();
        var connection = new Connector();
        connection.xPos = (inputNode.xPos + xPos) / 2;
        connection.yPos = (inputNode.yPos + yPos) / 2;
        connections.push(connection);
        
    });
/*         inputNodes.forEach((inputNode, inputIndex) => {
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            counterIndexHidden = index - inputIndex;
            numbersOccured.push(counterIndexHidden);

            

            counter++;
            
            

    }); */

    counter = 0;
    

}
function redrawHiddenHiddenConnections(xPos, yPos, layer, index) {

        layer.forEach((node, index) => {
            layer[index].connectedTo.push(node);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
            ctx.lineTo(node.xPos, node.yPos);
            ctx.stroke();

                var connection = new Connector();
                connection.xPos = (xPos + node.xPos) / 2;
                connection.yPos = (yPos + node.yPos) / 2;
                connections.push(connection);
        });
}
function redrawHiddenOutputConnections(xPos, yPos) {
    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
        ctx.lineTo(node.xPos, node.yPos);
        ctx.stroke();
            var connection = new Connector();
            connection.xPos = (xPos + node.xPos) / 2;
            connection.yPos = (yPos + node.yPos) / 2;
            connections.push(connection);
    });
}

function redrawAllConnections(xPos, yPos) {
    //redrawInputHiddenConnections(xPos, yPos);
    //redrawHiddenHiddenConnections();
    //redrawHiddenOutputConnections();
}

function redrawAllNodes() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas before redrawing
    redrawInputNodes();
    redrawHiddenNodes();
    redrawOutputNodes();
    }
    
    function redrawInputNodes() {
    inputNodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    node.drawInputNode(index, inputNodes.length);
    });
    }
    
    function redrawHiddenNodes() {
    hiddenLayers.forEach((layer, layerIndex) => {
    layer.forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
    node.drawHiddenNode(nodeIndex, layer.length);
    });
    });
    }

    function redrawOutputNodes() {
    outputNodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    node.drawOutputNode(index, outputNodes.length);
    });
    }
    function sigmoid(x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    }
    function train() {
        //Define variables
        var deltaError = 0; //error delta
        var sum = 0; //sum of weights
        var errorSum = 0; //error sum
        var valueCounter = 0; //value counter
        var valueCounter2 = 0; //value counter
        var numHiddenLayers = hiddenLayers.length; //number of hidden layers
        var hiddenLayerIndex = 1; //index of hidden layers
        var deltaWeights_ho = []; //array of weights
        var error_k = []; //error
        var deltaWeights_ih = []; //array of weights
        var error_j = []; //error

        //Clean inputs and normalize
        inputFeildsInputNode.forEach((inputFeild, index) => {
            cleanedInputs.push((inputFeild.value - min) / (max - min));
            inputNodes[index].value = cleanedInputs[index];
        });
        //Loop through first hidden layer and calculate values for each node of first hidden layer
            hiddenLayers[0].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
                inputNodes.forEach((inputNode, inputIndex) => {
                    sum+= inputNode.value * inputHiddenWeights[valueCounter].value;
                    valueCounter++;
                });
                node.value = sigmoid(sum);
                sum = 0;
            });
            valueCounter = 0;
            sum = 0;
            //Loop through all hidden layers and calculate values for each node of each hidden layer
            while(hiddenLayerIndex < numHiddenLayers) {
                hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
                    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
                        sum+= hiddenNode.value * hiddenHiddenWeights[valueCounter].value;
                        valueCounter++;
                    });
                    node.value = sigmoid(sum);
                    sum = 0;
                    
                        
                    sum = 0;
                });
                valueCounter = 0;
                sum = 0;
                hiddenLayerIndex++;
                valueCounter2 = 0;

            }
            //Loop through output nodes and calculate values for each output node
            outputNodes.forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
                hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
                    sum+= hiddenNode.value * hiddenOutputWeights[valueCounter].value;
                    valueCounter++;
                });
                node.value = sigmoid(sum);
                console.log(node.value);
                valueCounter = 0;
                //Loop through all output nodes and calculate error for each output node
                error_k[nodeIndex] = (inputFeildsOutputNode[nodeIndex].value - node.value);
                hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
                    deltaWeights_ho[valueCounter2] = -2 * error_k[nodeIndex] * hiddenNode.value * node.value * (1 - node.value);
                    hiddenOutputWeights[valueCounter2].value -= deltaWeights_ho[valueCounter2] * learningRate;
                    valueCounter2++;

                });

            });
            valueCounter2 = 0;
            valueCounter = 0;
            //Loop through all hidden layers and calculate error for each node of each hidden layer using the error of the output nodes and calculate delta weights for each connection between hidden and output nodes
            hiddenLayers[hiddenLayers.length - 1].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
                error_j[nodeIndex] = 0;
                error_k.forEach((error, index) => {
                    error_j[nodeIndex] += error * hiddenOutputWeights[valueCounter2].value;
                    valueCounter2++;
                });
                //error_j[nodeIndex] = error_j[nodeIndex] * node.value * (1 - node.value);
                valueCounter2 = outputNodes.length * valueCounter;
                deltaError = -2 * error_j[nodeIndex] * node.value * (1 - node.value);
            });
            valueCounter2 = 0;
            valueCounter = 0;
            sum = 0;
            hiddenLayerIndex = 1;
            //Loop through all hidden layers and calculate delta weights for each connection between hidden and hidden nodes
            while(hiddenLayerIndex < numHiddenLayers) {
                hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex].forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
                    hiddenLayers[hiddenLayerIndex - 1].forEach((hiddenNode, hiddenNodeIndex) => {
                        deltaError = -2 * error_j[nodeIndex] * node.value * (1 - node.value) * hiddenNode.value;
                        hiddenHiddenWeights[valueCounter2].value -= deltaError * learningRate;
                        valueCounter2++;
                        });

                });
                hiddenLayerIndex++;
            }
                
                valueCounter = 0;
                sum = 0;
                outputNodes.forEach((node, nodeIndex) => {
                    console.log(node.value);
                });
            valueCounter2 = 0;
            valueCounter = 0;
            sum = 0;



        console.log("Training the neural network...");
        // Add your neural network training logic here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that caught may attention is that the learning rate seems too large. Try decreasing it to 0.001 or some value near this. Large learning rates tend to cause the loss function oscillate or increase.

[image: Loss value change with different learning rates]

Also, when you click the button, does the function calculated only one forward-backward pass? In general you need a lot more training loops (aka epochs) for the neural network parameters to converge on a successful state. You can try 100 training loops for example each time you click.

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. And for the training function I was planning to later implement the feature to run multiple epochs and allow a dataset input. But for the time being I manually change the inputs and every time the train button is pressed it runs the back propagation once. Although this neural network was supposed to be more educational and make people interested and see how fun neural networks are.